# hidden input value from php foreach loop not properly passing to JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

HTML + PHP :

```
<?php foreach ($resultpics as $row1){ ?>
<div class="col-md-2">
<a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-popup-open="popup-1"<!-onclick="showImg(<?php //echo $row1['img_id']; ?>-->)">
<input type="hidden" name="imgid" value="<?php echo $row1['img_id']; ?>" id="imgid">
<img id="popimg" src="<?php echo $row1['img_path'];?>/<?php echo $row1['img_id']; ?>.jpg" alt="Pulpit Rock" style="width:200px;height:150px;">  
</a>
</div>  
<?php } ?>
```

JQuery:

```
$('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
    var imgid = $('input[name=imgid]').val();
    alert(imgid);
    $('img#viewimg').attr('src','images/'+imgid+'.jpg');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The problem is the value of

```
var imgid
```

is always same(on every different it gives the imgid of first image only). Note that there is no problem in php foreach loop, it fetch's correctly. Thanks

Comment: You cant use id attribute in `foreach` without any unique number. it will generate same id for all hidden fields.

Comment: I do have a question. In your last jQuery line, you are replacing the `src` of the `<img id='viewimg'>` element. However, you are replacing it with the image's ID, and not with the image's path. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is you have multiple input elements having name="imgid". So when you query **$('input[name=imgid]')** jquery parses  all of the DOM and creates an object having 0 to 'n' input tags (*n being the number of elements matching your query*). If you use val() on this object it will always return the value of 0'th element in the object.

Solution:

change this

```
var imgid = $('input[name=imgid]').val();
```

to this

```
var imgid = $(this).next().val();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Better approach:** Since you're iterating over `$resultpics` to build HTML, then you need to use `classes` rather than `ids`, since duplicate IDs will be inconsistent HTML. Also, since you are using data attributes like `data-popup-open` make use of jQuery's **[`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** method, Do it this way:

```
<?php foreach ($resultpics as $row1) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-popup-open="popup-1">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row1['img_id']; ?>" class="imgid">
            <img class="popimg" src="<?php echo $row1['img_path']; ?>/<?php echo $row1['img_id']; ?>.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<script>
    $(".thumbnail").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var class_name = $(this).data('popup-open');
        $('[data-popup="' + class_name + '"]').fadeIn(350);
        var imgid = $(this).find('.imgid').val();
        $('img#viewimg').attr('src', 'images/' + imgid + '.jpg');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I would do the same.
And I think it's possible to simplify with : `var imgpath = $(this).find('img').prop('src');` then just do `$('img#viewimg').attr('src', imgpath);` . This way, you can remove the `input type="hidden"` because it become useless.

Comment: I thought so too. I asked this on my comment above, on the OP's question.. Guess it depends exactly what they need, but I get what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line in your jquery:

```
  var imgid = $('input[name=imgid]').val(); // wrong
```

to:

```
  var imgid = $(this+' :input').val();
```

i'd also remove/change the id and name attribute values - as they should be unique

Comment: not working. In your code, there is no mentioning of name or id of input element

Comment: you can select anything by anything in js - it doesnt have to have an name or id

Comment: what if i have multiple hidden values in same page, same scope

Comment: 'var imgid = $(this).find('input:hidden').val();' this worked for me ! thanks for your help and i still have that question of multiple hidden values

Comment: Then give them a class!

Answer (score 0):

`var imgid = $('input[name=imgid]');` returns all the inputs but when you call the `val()` function it only returns the value of the first item in the array which is always the same in this case.

You should either use a for-loop or add an index to your current foreach loop:

```html
<?php 
  $index = 0;

  foreach ($resultpics as $row1) { 
?>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-popup-open="popup-<?php echo $index; ?>" data-index="<?php echo $index; ?>">
    
    <input type="hidden" name="imgid_<?php echo $index; ?>" value="<?php echo $row1['img_id']; ?>">
    <img id="popimg" src="<?php echo $row1['img_path'];?>/<?php echo $row1['img_id']; ?>.jpg" 
      alt="Pulpit Rock" style="width:200px;height:150px;">  
  </a>
</div>  
<?php
    $index++;
  } 
?>
```

Then use the index in the data to retrieve the input field:

```js
$('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
    var index = jQuery(this).attr('data-index');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
    var imgid = $('input[name=imgid_' + index +']').val();
    alert(imgid);
    $('img#viewimg').attr('src','images/'+imgid+'.jpg');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Carefull, your `$index` is not incremented.